# What is the asymptotic bound for the ratio of sample mean and expectation？

Tags: estimation, convergence, asymptotics, probability-inequalities

For an i.i.d. observations $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ (bounded), we have the Hoeffding's inequality that establishes the upper bound for the tail probability of $|\bar{X_n}-\mathbb{E}[X_1]|$. I would like to ask whether we have some similar results for the ratio of its sample mean and expectation, i.e. $|\bar{X_n}/\mathbb{E}[X_1]|$ provided that $\mathbb{E}[X_1] \neq 0$?

Simply using $\log$ does not work since (i) $X_i$ may become unbounded; (ii) $\log\mathbb{E}[X_1]\neq\mathbb{E}[\log X_1]$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the fact that $\bar{X}_n-E(X_1)$ divided through by $E(X_1)$, $=\frac{\bar{X}_n}{E(X_1)}-1$ help?

Comment: Simply apply any inequality you like to the random variables $X_n/E[X_1],$ which merely re-express the original variables using a different unit of measurement.

Comment: Yes...it turns out to be a trivial question. Thank you @Glen_b and @whuber!